Message has been not received in AWS Lambda or capture by AWS CloudWatch log stream from the AWS ActiveMQ Queues
ActiveMQ message is not received by the AWS Lambda and Cloudwatch logs stream.

Message has been deleted from the ActiveMQ queue but message is not processed by Lambda and neither any exception message is captured by the Cloudwatch log stream.

Message is received from ActiveMQ queue by lambda and processed it successfully but there is no logs in the Cloudwatch log stream.


This issue was faced in production environments.
We have gone through the ActiveMQ queues from there message has been deleted. There is no success or failure of the messages capture by the AWS CloudWatch Logs.
In another instances message has been successfully processed by the AWS Lambda from the ActiveMQ but there is no trace of the messages in the AWS CloudWatch Log Stream.
I need your help on the above-mentioned issue that why such issues are crop-up. I have checked ActiveMQ triggers configuration to the Lambda and the IAM Role also. Our application is working fine but there are some instances where we are facing such issues.
